# Converting pandas dataframe to PySpark dataframe drops index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I've got a pandas dataframe called `data_clean`. It looks like this:
[image]

I want to convert it to a Spark dataframe, so I use the [createDataFrame()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.SparkSession.createDataFrame.html) method:
`sparkDF = spark.createDataFrame(data_clean)`

However, that seems to drop the index column (the one that has the names ali, anthony, bill, etc) from the original dataframe. The output of

```
sparkDF.printSchema()
sparkDF.show()
```

is

```
root
 |-- transcript: string (nullable = true)

+--------------------+
|          transcript|
+--------------------+
|ladies and gentle...|
|thank you thank y...|
| all right thank ...|
|                    |
|this is dave he t...|
|                    |
|   ladies and gen...|
|   ladies and gen...|
|armed with boyish...|
|introfade the mus...|
|wow hey thank you...|
|hello hello how y...|
+--------------------+
```

The docs say createDataFrame() can take a `pandas.DataFrame` as an input.  I'm using Spark version '3.0.1'.

Other questions on SO related to this don't mention this problem of the index column disappearing:

- [This one about converting Pandas to Pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52943627/convert-a-pandas-dataframe-to-a-pyspark-dataframe) doesn't mention this issue of the index column disappearing.
- Same with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41826553/convert-between-spark-sql-dataframe-and-pandas-dataframe)
- And [this one relates to data dropping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50120805/pyspark-dataframe-conversion-to-pandas-drops-data) during conversion, but is more about window functions.

I'm probably missing something obvious, but how do I get to keep the index column when I convert from a pandas dataframe to a PySpark dataframe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spark DataFrame has no concept of index, so if you want to preserve it, you have to assign it to a column first using `reset_index` in a pandas dataframe

You can also use `inplace` to avoid additional memory overhead while resting the index

```
df.reset_index(drop=False,inplace=True)

sparkDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(df)
```

Comment: Both AdibP and Vaebhav's answers worked. I "accepted" the latter because of the explanation that "Spark DataFrame has no concept of an index", which made it really clear to me. Both approaches worked, and I liked the succinctness aspect and the rename_axis() feature of AdibP's answer.

Answer (score 4):

Use Pandas dataframe's `reset_index` method when converting to Spark dataframe. You can also use `rename_axis` to name it.

```
sparkDF = spark.createDataFrame(data_clean.rename_axis('name').reset_index())
```